# CSS set element width by screen width

Tags: javascript, css

Someone can give me a source code on jsfiddle when width jquery can set the css by change the window size?

My englist not so good i tryo to search on the net but not found.

Comment: Do you mean `width: 100%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript example: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ShyYn/2/)

Change element CSS on resize:

If the `viewport` width is less than `800`, then it will change the width of the `#test` div

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="width"></h1>
<div id="test"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test { width:200px; height:50px; background:red; }
```

Javascript

```
// set the initial width
var viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var el = document.getElementById("width");
el.innerHTML = viewportWidth + "px";

// on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){

    var viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    var el = document.getElementById("width");

    el.innerHTML = viewportWidth + "px";

    if(viewportWidth < 800){
        test.style.width = "500px";
    }
});
```

Comment: its great but where can setv an css element by size?

Comment: @user3327101 I've updated my answer to show you how to change an element width on resize.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

If your element has the class `element`

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".element").css("width", window.innerWidth;);
});
```

Then you could do something like `window.innerWidth/2` or `window.innerWidth - 50`.

Comment: yeand where i can set the css by size?

Comment: @user3327101 I just made an edit to show that.